# selenium with python button click

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I can access the tag below via css_selector but how do I do a button click?

```
<a title="Sign In" onclick="toggleLogin('signInBlock','regBenefitsBlock');" href="javascript:void(0);">Sign In</a>
```

Any idea would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Locate the button [by link text](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element_by_link_text) and use [`click()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.click) method:

```
button = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Sign In")
button.click()
```

Answer (score 1):

To execute JavaScript on selenium python you can use:

```
driver.execute_script("toggleLogin('signInBlock','regBenefitsBlock');")
```